# How to Create Custom Generate/Scaffold Templates(Razor) in ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, code-generation, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

How to Create Custom Generate/Scaffold Templates(Razor) or Modify Default in ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2017?

I want to add or modify code generator for **ASP.Net MVC** project **not ASP.NET Core.**

I found Razor Template in

> `C:\Users\....\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.0.0\Templates\ViewGenerator`

but can not change them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather, you need to understand the technology T4. Templates are stored in the * .tt file. There are a lot of things to be said here, but here are useful links.

[MSDN T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017)

[Other examples](https://www.tritac.com/blog/code-generationscaffolding-with-visual-studio-t4-templates/)